# Deixar o select colorido

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
<select>
    <option>opção1</option>
    <option>opção2</option>
    <option>opção3</option>
    <option>opção4</option>
    <option>opção5</option>
</select>
```

Gostaria de faze-lo ficar colorido. por exemplo:

```
opção1: cinza
opção2: branco
opção3: cinza
opção4: branco
opção5: cinza
```

Sendo que não sei quantas opções podem ter (a qualquer momento pode ser que seja adicionada mais uma opção)

Como posso fazer isso?
Obrigada.

Comment: Tem alguma ideia do que pode fazer? No CSS existe o seletor `nth-child`, conhece? Quer tentar?

Comment: Adicionar evento onclick no select e depois verificar com com `if` e depois mudar com color com alguma classe ou id em css.